Set metadata in TIFF files with gdalUtilities?
I'd like to modify the metadata of a TIFF file, in particular the TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION, TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION and the TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT in which they are expressed. Is this possible with R? With gdalUtilities? If so, how?
For example, how could I execute the following gdal command from R?
gdal_translate in.tiff out.tif -mo {TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION}=200

Thank you.
Jean-Luc
